# 0% | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s] error while building docx to pdf converter using docx2pdf python package

Tags: python, docx2pdf

I am using Mac and trying to build a converter that converts docx file to pdf file. I am using docx2pdf python package.

```
from docx2pdf import convert

convert('my.docx')
```

[image]

When I run the code, I am getting **"  0%|          | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]" error**

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem like an error, it's a `progress bar`.

Comment: Another converter is available via LibreOffice - with the additional advantage that MS Word **need not be installed.** Installation of (free) LibreOffice however is required. Command `lowriter --headless --convert-to pdf wordfile.docx`.